# Is it appropriate to do a t-test with z-scores?

Tags: t-test, z-score

I would like to test for significance of some sample data. However, I only have the z-scores of individual observations. Is it appropriate to make a claim about the sample as a whole by doing a t-test from the individual z-scores? Are there any assumptions to testing significance if z-scores are being used instead of raw data?

Based on the comments, it seems like a t-test is not the statistical test that is needed, but rather a z-test. I thought it was strange as I read a z-test does not depend on the size of the sample. So how could I make a claim about the sample as a whole without considering the sample size (n). After further reading, I think I may be able to evaluate the the null hypothesis that the sample data is not different than the population data using the below method:

Z = mean(individual z-scores) * sqrt(n)

Then use this Z in the z-table to evaluate the corresponding p-value.

I realize the typical way would be to use the raw data, but I cannot evaluate the raw data, and must use the individual z-scores.

Comment: When the sample size is very large the critical values for the t statistics approaches the z scores.  So sometime people use the z score as an approximation in large samples.

Comment: Are these z-scores using the same mean and standard deviation for all the observations you're comparing? [How were those means and standard deviations obtained?]

Comment: @Glen_b the z-scores are determined from a growth curve. Thus, the mean and standard deviation are a function of age. Since the sample is a pediatric population of various ages, each individual observation is transformed to a z-score. I have the raw data (age and height) and z-scores of individual observations, but I do not have the growth function, so I cannot use the raw data. Therefore I believe I must use the z-scores if I am to determine if the sample is part of the larger population.

Comment: So you're actually talking about standardized *residuals*? What hypothesis are you trying to test with them?

Comment: @Glen_b I am testing the following null hypothesis: The sample's height-per-age is not significantly different than the population growth charts produced by WHO anthropometric data.

Comment: Okay, I think I may finally understand what you're asking (it's not at all clear in your original question; it would be useful to put that explanation in your question). But if you're using the WHO charts to "standardize" your own sample, why can't you compare your raw sample of height-vs-age directly with the values you used to standardize it?

Comment: @Glen_b The z-values produced by a WHO software that identifies where an individual falls on the growth curve by producing a z-score for an individual observation. Unfortunately I don't have the function used to produce the z-score. But I'm thinking I should still be able to evaluate the null hypothesis from just the z-scores?

Comment: Again, this is useful information to include in your question. Yes, there's a couple of ways this information could be used to test consistency with the WHO charts.

Comment: @Glen_b I guess I am also assuming that since the individual z-scores are acting like a standard residual, I could group males and females together, as long as their z-score is determined from the appropriate growth curve?

Comment: added a brief comment to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume independence and approximate normality of observed values around their own population curve, you could construct an asymptotic chi-squared statistic to test for any form of deviation from the WHO charts by summing the squared $Z$ values. Since the parameters are all determined outside the sample, the chi-squared statistic should have $n$ degrees of freedom. [However rejection could as easily imply an under-estimate  of the variation about the model as an issue with the location of the curve.]

If you want a test for a directional shift (an overall tendency to be larger or an overall tendency to be smaller) you could instead sum the Z values and (under the same assumptions) compare with a $N(0,n)$

[It would also be possible to test general deviations by testing the set of $Z$ values by goodness-of-fit testing for a standard normal but that would - naturally - tend to be much more directly sensitive to the assumption of normality. I wouldn't advise this approach.]

If you instead assume symmetry and independence, you could test directional shift with a sign test and consistency more broadly with a runs test.

Note that if your curves are obtained by following individuals through time, the assumption of independence might not be tenable; more suitable models would be needed for that.

---

*Combining males and females even though they would have different growth curves*
 -- this should be possible for the chi-square test and the sum-of-Z tests I mentioned. With the sign test I mentioned it should also work.

The runs test would not, however -- you couldn't just jam the two series together, you'd need to combine the two test statistics. If the series are large enough to use the normal approximation you could add the two; the hypothesized mean of the number of runs should be the sum of the component means and the variance should be the sum of the variances.

Answer (score 1):

You have z-data. Why do t-test? z-data assumes that you already know the population variance. So if you are confident that your data is normal, you get get the exact tail size from the z-score. If your alternate hypothesis is that the data come from different populations, then how did you get your z-score anyway?

Comment: This is not necessarily the case because you don't know the variance.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what the WHO anthropometric scores are like.